# Событие при скролле и ширине экрана

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть хедер, элементы которого при скролле получают доп. css стили. Однако, нужно чтобы это условие работало только при ширине экрана/устройства < 920 пикселей.

Пробую выполнить `if ($(window).scrollTop() > 40, $(window).width() < 920)`— не работает. Задача в том, чтобы условие выполнялось для ширины 920 и меньше, не затрагивая имеющиеся стили. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
function changecolor() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > 40) {
      $("#c1").css("color" , "#3a3a3a");
      $("#m2").css("background" , "#rgba(255,255,255,.8)");
      $(".c-color").css("color" , "#3a3a3a");
      $(".m-color").css("color" , "#3a3a3a");
    }
    else {
      $("#c1").css("color" , "#fff");
      $("#m2").css("background" , "rgba(255,255,255,0)");
      $(".c-color").css("color" , "#fff");
      $(".m-color").css("color" , "#f4f4f4");
    }
};
```

Comment: Попробуйте `if ($(window).scrollTop() > 40 && $(window).width() < 920)`

Comment: Не работает. :(

Comment: Покажите ваш полный код.

Comment: Добавил код в начальном посте.

Comment: тот код который вы показали должен выполняться только при ширене <920?

Comment: Так точно. Эти стили не должны работать для хедера, если его ширина больше 920.

Comment: А Вы можете весь код привести, сделать воспроизводимый пример?

Comment: `changecolor` как и где используется?

Comment: https://codepen.io/dis6/pen/NWqxzNy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как-то так

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).scroll(function(){
     if ( $(window).width() <920 ) {
       var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll > 40) {
          $("#overhead").css("background" , "rgba(255,255,255,1)");
          $(".c-1").css("color" , "blue");
          $(".m-1").css("color" , "blue");
        }
        else{
          $("#overhead").css("background" , "grey");
          $(".c-1").css("color" , "red");
          $(".m-1").css("color" , "orange");
        }
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Не работает к сожалению.

Comment: @Стас добавь тут снипет или на кодеопен или еще куда залей

Comment: https://codepen.io/dis6/pen/NWqxzNy

Comment: @Стас поправил вроде работает
вместе всего своего js этот вставь